# Linker Error with ICC Pointer Checking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, icc

I am using Intel C++ 13.0.1.119 Build 20121008 for IA-32 running on Windows in Visual Studio 2012. I've been having issues with linker errors and have narrowed it down to the option `/Qcheck-pointers:rw`. Whenever I compile with `/Qcheck-pointers:rw`, I get the following errors:

```
1>  xilink: executing 'link'
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invalid_parameter@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invoke_watson(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invoke_watson@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __call_reportfault already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __get_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __initp_misc_invarg already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: ___pInvalidArgHandler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'libcmt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Y:\...\ : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I found [this article](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-389D8F46-C207-40B8-8ED3-A0827894C6FF.htm), indicating that it could be solved by turning off checking for undimensioned arrays using `/Qcheck-pointers-undimensioned-`. However, this seemed to have no effect, and I got the same linker errors.

Does anyone know how to fix this linking issue?

**Update:** As per Eric Shiyin Kang's suggestion, I left `/Qcheck-pointers:rw` and `/Qcheck-pointers-undimensioned-` on the command line, but added `/NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib` as a linker command. This resulted in me getting a different linker error:

```
1>  xilink: executing 'link'
1>libcpmt.lib(nothrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(nothrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj)
1>Y:\..\.exe : fatal error LNK1319: 2 mismatches detected
```

**Update 2:**
Here is the full compiler command line:

```
/RTCc /GS /Qcheck-pointers:rw /debug:expr-source-pos /W5 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"\..\include\gtest" /I"\..\include\" /Zi /Od /Qintel-extensions- /Fd"Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_VARIADIC_MAX=10" /D "_MBCS" /Qipo /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Qcheck-pointers-undimensioned- /Gd /MTd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Za /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Project2.pch"
```

Here is the full linker command line:

```
/OUT:"\..\Project2.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"\..\Project2.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "gtestd.lib" "gtest_maind.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH / /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\Project2.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"\..\include\gtest\debug_build" /TLBID:1 /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib
```

I am using the GTest library and am using the Multi-Threaded Debug runtime library, to match GTest.

Comment: It seems you linked libcmt and libcmtd simultaneously. The err msg suggests you use `/NODEFAULTLIB:library`. Have u tried that?

Comment: @EricShiyinKang I did, but it seems like the ICL linker doesn't recognize that. I get the warning `icl : warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/NODEFAULTLIB:library'`. All the errors remain the same.

Comment: Maybe the exact option you should pass to linker/compiler is `/NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib`. On the other hand, it seems you mix debug/release libs together. You could check if the libs you links match your compiling mode.

Comment: @EricShiyinKang I tied that, and got a different linker error. See my update above.

Comment: Try to repeat all this in debug mode then, especially when you aim to check pointers.

Comment: @EricShiyinKang What do you mean? This is already in debug mode.

Comment: Seems you linked a lot of release mode lib. Only those who have suffix 'd' are debug mode lib. You may want to show a full list of your project settings and/or code to see if there is any conflict.

Comment: @EricShiyinKang I added another update to include the full linker/compiler command lines. Is there any other information I should add?

Comment: Try compiler option `/MDd` instead of `/MTd`. I think `/MDd` is default. Why you changed that?

Comment: @EricShiyinKang Because GTest is `/MTd`. I can try building it for `/MDd`. Shouldn't it not make a difference?

Comment: `/MTd` may pack libcmtd.lib/libcmt.lib into gtestd.lib, and when you use `/MTd` in your project, it may pack libcmtd.lib again. Then you will have 2 versions of libcmtd.lib/libcmt.lib in your final .exe, which may lead to the conflict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the discussion, and since you use a manually built library `gtestd.lib` in your project of `Project2.exe`, I think the problem is you are trying to pack different versions of C run-time lib such as `libcmt.lib/libcmtd.lib` into your executable file `Project2.exe`, either by static linking or by dynamic linking.

One is packed into `gtestd.lib` by the option `/MTd` in gtest project and then you are trying to pack `gtestd.lib` into `Project2.exe`.

The other one will be packed into `Project2.exe` directly by `/MTd` in the project of `Project2.exe`.

The solution could be

1) use `/MDd`,`/MTd`,`/MD` or `/MTd` constantly in all the projects involved, or

2) don't link any external libraries in, when building a static/dynamic library such as `gtest.lib`, by using `/NODEFAULTLIB` or `/NODEFAULTLIB:<name_of_some_of_def_libs>`. And only link those libs when building the executable files.

Comment: You just saved my life, This is valuable info.